# pyspark randomsplit returns null

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am new to spark so I apologize if my question is very basic :)
I have a spark dataframe that I want to split into train and test sets using randomSplit() method. This task should be very easy but I don't know why it returns dataframe with null values. Below is my code:

```
train = spark.read.csv('training.csv', header=True)

train = train.withColumn("reviewerID", train["reviewerID"].cast("int"))
train = train.withColumn("asin", train["asin"].cast("int"))
train = train.withColumn("overall", train["overall"].cast("double"))
train_selected = train.select("reviewerID", "asin", "overall")
train_selected.show(5)

+----------+-----+-------+
|reviewerID| asin|overall|
+----------+-----+-------+
|     15012|52021|    4.0|
|     20330|42867|    5.0|
|     62907| 9168|    5.0|
|     11778|26051|    4.0|
|     63717|30061|    4.0|
+----------+-----+-------+
only showing top 5 rows

splits = train_selected.randomSplit([0.8, 0.2], 13)
splits[0].show(5)

+----------+----+-----------+
|reviewerID|asin|    overall|
+----------+----+-----------+
|      null|null|       null|
|      null|null|1.3532832E9|
|      null|null| 1.353456E9|
|      null|null|1.3568256E9|
|      null|null| 1.356912E9|
+----------+----+-----------+
only showing top 5 rows
```

I appreciate your help.

Comment: Did you check if ```train_selected``` contains those values? After split you won't have the same ordering, so ```show``` can show different things. I'd suspect that in original dataset not all of the values can be directly cast to types you are casting to and thus nulls.

Comment: check the counts before & after splitting casting

Comment: @Daniel: yes. I checked the train_selected and it looks ok. I also checked the data for any anomaly or null values. Nothing!

@ Sarath I also checked the count. It looks fine. It doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Did you try to type "seed=13", instead of just "13" in the line:                            splits = train_selected.randomSplit([0.8, 0.2], 13)

Comment: @aravanshad even I am getting the same problem did you solve it, if yes let me know the answer